# Multiple conditions in Regex_Replace

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to replace special characters from two different words as shown in the image below. From the first word, I want to replace a special character with "I" and from the second word, I want to replace a special character with "U".
My query is like below: It works for the first word. Can you pls assist?

```
SELECT 
   distinct ABC REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(ABC, r'([^\p{ASCII}]+)', 'I') ,r'\&', 'U') 
FROM Table 
where ABC like '%B??RD%' or ABC like '%M??D%';
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide data for us to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Data is the first column of the table. I need output as 2nd column.

Comment: Have you tried CASE or REPLACE instead of using REGEX?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using REGEX, you can use `CASE` for this scenario:

```
WITH CTE as (
SELECT  'B��RD'as ABC,
UNION ALL SELECT 'M��D'as ABC)

SELECT 
   ABC,
   CASE ABC
    WHEN 'B��RD' THEN 'BIRD'
    WHEN 'M��D' THEN 'MUD'
   END AS output

FROM CTE
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I want to use nested regex_replace. It doesn't work.

Comment: You may opt to use the solution above, I updated my answer with proven result.